# How to validate XSD schema in java? I am getting different ans when i hanle integer datatype

Tags: java, xsd

I want to validate AGE filed in my schema but i have given some restriction on it but when i give the string value in AGE filed which is not throwing the error like "Invalid data for AGE". May i know how to solve this issue? Please find my sample code below.

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employee>
    <AGE>thf</AGE>
</Employee>
```

XSD File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Employee">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="AGE">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="65"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
     </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Take a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884084/java-xml-schema-validation)

Comment: Hi Shashank, My schema is working fine. When i give wrong data in AGE field. Which is not throwing the error.

Comment: Can you share your code where you are validating ? and the output ?

Comment: Sry Shashank, We are using JAXB concept in Java to validate XSD Schema.

Comment: If you have set the schema to your marshaller or Unmarshaller, it should throw a `JAXBException`. Unless you don't show what you are actually trying I wonder if anyone would be able to help you.