# XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace

Tags: xml

This is my first time creating a xbrl document but I am having problems with one line not working.  can anyone tell me what I have done wrong

```
<us-gaap:Cash contextRef="Feb022013" unitRef="USD" decimals="-3" >231501</us-gaap:Cash>
```

Answer (score 27):

Check on top of the code following code is placed under svg.. In most cases we miss any of these..

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue because I had defined two closing `</urlset>`

After I fixed this error, it parsed fine.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you did not bind an XML prefix to its namespace.
That's not XBRL specific, it's usual XML. See for instance [Java XML Schema validation: prefix not bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884084/java-xml-schema-validation)

So, somewhere in your document (usually at the root) you should have:

```
xmlns:us-gaap="…"
```

So, probably something like

```
<xbrl xmlns:us-gaap="http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2013-01-31" …>
```