# XML to CSV conversion using java, tag with colon problem

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am not able to display the value of xml tag using namespace - tag with colon.

When there are no colons in tags, code works perfectly, but as soon I want to display a tag which contains colon, program doesnt throw any error, only doesn`t show any value.

Here is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:inv="http://www.w3schools.com/daco" xmlns:lst="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0" version="1.0">
   <lst:howto>
      <topic id="1">
         <nieco>
            <lst:title>Java</lst:title>
         </nieco>
      </topic>
   </lst:howto>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:lst="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      topic
      <xsl:for-each select="//nieco">
         <xsl:value-of select="lst:title" />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and Java:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

    class XMLtoCsVConversion2 {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            File stylesheet = new File("C:/java/howto.xsl");
            File xmlSource = new File("C:/java/howto.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

            StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                    .newTransformer(stylesource);
            Source source = new DOMSource(document);
            Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("xyz.csv"));
            transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
            System.out.println("done");
            
        }
    }
```

Codes really simplified to find the cause of the problem, but I was not able to figure it out.
If I would remove lst: from tag in xml and from xsl, it would work, as soon there is colon, program doesn`t show any value.
But XML we receive contain plenty of tags with colon, so I would a solution to this problem.

Please if you have any idea where could be the problem, please let me know :)

Expected output:

topic
Java

Comment: can you try JAXB , marshalling and unmarshalling, will help you convert xml to java object and can use your logic to convert to csv.  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

Comment: You probably need to call [setNamespaceAware(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)) on your DocumentBuilderFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File stylesheet = new File("C:/java/howto.xsl");
        File xmlSource = new File("C:/java/howto.xml");

//        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
//        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
//        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                .newTransformer(stylesource);
        //Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        Source source = new StreamSource(xmlSource);
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("C:/java/xyz.csv"));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
        System.out.println("done");

    }
```

Comment: Hi Erandika, many thanks, it helped, but now I receive "The prefix "typ" for element "typ:id" is not bound." error message:( I tried solution in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884084/java-xml-schema-validation-prefix-not-bound. , but it didn`t help: Could you please help?

Comment: @bennes, Could you please post your new xml and xsl?